# REST API on EC2 Stops running after a few hours

Tags: rest, amazon-ec2, webserver

I am trying to run a very simple REST API backend on EC2 for an Android App I am making for a school project. In a previous project, I used a NodeJS library, [expressJS](http://expressjs.com/), to quickly create a backend that executes SQL updates/queries, and in the current project, I am using Java and a Java library called [Spark](https://sparktutorials.github.io/) to do the same thing (SQL queries/updates). I start a refreshed backend with

```
git pull; mvn clean install; mvn exec:java;
```

because I am using Maven. Anyway for both the previous ExpressJS and the current Spark backend, I can talk to the server for an hour or two perhaps, then I have to restart it. Why doesn't it just keep running? Is there some problem with my connection to the database leaking memory? You can check out the [project here](https://github.com/Njanderson/EvenSimplerSyndication). I tried using nohup, but that didn't do it either; it still crashed after a few hours. It's not getting too many requests. Any other comments on improvements to my process or backend are welcome as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not close my database connections. The server kept open the connection until crashing.